# Regular expression very slow. Trying to extract multiple strings

Tags: regex

I am fairly new to Regular Expressions and practicing a little with Notepad++. I am trying to extract some stock related data from Yahoo but somewhat lack the experience. Maybe somebody could give me a hand. It would be highly appreciated.

An example of what I try to parse is:

```
<strong>230.00</strong></a></td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><a href="http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AMZN121026C00230000">AMZN121026C00230000</a></td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right"><b>9.35</b></td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right"><span id="yfs_c10_amzn121026c00230000"><img style="margin-right:-2px;" src="op_files/up_g.gif" alt="Up" border="0" height="14" width="10"> <span class="yfi-price-change-green">0.35</span></span></td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">9.25</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">9.40</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">3,857</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">1,041</td></tr><tr><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap="nowrap">
```

I basically try to extract the numbers 230.00, 9.35, 0.35, 9.25, 9.40, 3,857, 1,041. What 
What I managed so far is:

```
<strong>(\d.*?)</strong>.*?<b>(.*?)<
```

But it is really slow. Is that correct so far?

Comment: Generally, parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea....

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Specifically, can you identify what you have done to demonstrate the the regex is slow vs. your connection to Yahoo, etc?  Also, what are your expectations for performance here that aren't being met (and what led you to those expectations)?

Comment: Notepad++ has terrible regex support. Perhaps find an online regex tester instead?

Comment: @SomeKittens: Well, regex has been recommended to me so I go with that for now. If you have a better solution I am all ears.

Comment: Use an HTML parser for whatever language/platform you normally use.

Comment: try this `\<strong\>(\d.*?)<\/strong\>.*<b>(\d.*)<\/b>`

Comment: If you are specifically trying to look for stock information, a more predictable approach would be to use the RSS feeds - http://finance.yahoo.com/rssindex (scraping HTML can be tough when the presentation structure changes).

Comment: @jheddings: I managed <strong>(\d.*?)</strong> which when I use it in Notepad++ gives me immediate feedback by jumping in the text. When I go for <strong>(\d.*?)</strong>.*?<b>(.*?)< I have a one second lag before a result is shown. It seems to me that some heavy parsing is started but I do not know why. I assume I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Oded: I intend to use VBA Excel because I want to display the data processed in Excel.

Comment: First time I see VBA Excel mentioned in this question. What other languages do you know?

Comment: @jheddings: For the data I want Yahoo is absolutely sufficient. No worries here. But if there is a easier way I am listening.

Comment: @Oded: VBA is just a means and it is not troubling me. My question is only about Regex which I do not have much experience about. Please ignore my need for VBA. I know the typical ones (C, C++, C#, ...)

Comment: I am asking as if your platform/language has a known good HTML parser, that would be a better option (beautiful soup for python, the HTML Agility Pack for .NET languages etc...)

Comment: @IshKumar And why would arbitrarily escaping things that don't need to be escaped improve performance  (`/<>`, none of these characters have to be escaped)? If anything, it would make it marginally worse.

Comment: @Oded: Well, I can't really answer your question. I normally never do anything with HTML. Hope I get away this time also. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible faster variant could be `(?<=>)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=<)`
it only matches only the numbers between > and < an ignores the rest...

but keep in mind, like SomeKittens said: "Generally, parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea...."

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working perfectly. I will keep the warning in mind.

Comment: nope. Dot in square brackets makes no sense and this way you wont find values above 999

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I meant >([\d\.]+)<

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aS7vD2)

You can have this example, will match the `tag` and its number so you can do whatever you want with them. You can even filter by tag changing `[a-z]+` by `(span|b|td|whatever)`